# How can I multiply all elements of a list together with user-defined multiplicatoin?

Tags: list-manipulation, products

so currently I have my own definition of multiplication between elements but it can only multiply two elements.

```
MyMult[a_,b_]:=...
```

I want to multiply all elements in a list together with it i.e.

```
L = {a,b,c,d}
Ans = MyMult[MyMult[MyMult[a,b],c],d]
```

This however is messy and I want to create a function that takes in an arbitrarily sized list and outputs this product with MyMult.

Any thoughts on a neat/efficient way of doing it? Preferably one-liner sort of deal so I can define a function with it.

Comment: Perhaps [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) might help?

Comment: `Fold[myMult, L]`?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `SetAttributes[MyMult, Flat]` might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fold[myMult, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> myMult[myMult[myMult[a, b], c], d]